# How to dismiss 3D-touched notification with custom action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, 3dtouch

I am implementing a kind of alert notification for my app, using `UserNotifications`. When 3D-touching this notification, I want it to display some 'alert information', and the option to "Snooze" the alert, which will effectively repeat the notification in 5 minutes.
This is all working fine, except that the notification doesn't get dismissed when I click the Snooze button.

I am using a `NotificationContentExtension` to modify the content, with the categoryIdentifier `"ReminderNotificationExtensionCategory"`. Then I have created my category in code like this:

```
let snooze = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "snoozeActionIdentifier", title: NSLocalizedString("SNOOZE", comment: ""), options: .foreground)
let reminderCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "ReminderNotificationExtensionCategory", actions: [snooze], intentIdentifiers: [], options: .customDismissAction)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([reminderCategory])//Not sure if I should set this every time or just once..
```

Then I create my notification object

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()        
content.categoryIdentifier = "ReminderNotificationExtensionCategory"
content.title = "test"
content.body = "test"
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false) //Fire in 3 seconds
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "someIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error:Error?) in /**/}
```

Now, my notification will be sent in 3 seconds.
I lock my screen and receive it, and it looks great. When I 3D-touch it, my extension is launched, and I get a sneak peak on a `UIView` I have set up, along with my "Snooze"-button below the notification, as shown in the image:(content removed)[image: Notification]

When I click the "Snooze"-button, a `UNNotificationContentExtension` delegate-method will be called, specifically `func didReceive(_ response: completion:)`
The completion only accepts a value of `UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption`, which would be either `.dismiss`, `.doNotDismiss`, or `.dismissAndForwardAction`.
Just for testing, I have done this:

```
func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {
    print("This is happening. ActionIdentifier: ", response.actionIdentifier)
    completion(.dismiss)
}
```

And when I debug the notification extension, the print does really happen. It prints out `"This is happening. ActionIdentifier:  snoozeActionIdentifier"`. However, the notification is not being dismissed.
If I change from `.dismiss` to `.doNotDismiss`, nothing changes. It still does not dismiss. If I change to `.dismissAndForwardAction`, it dismisses and opens my app.

I can't find anyone with this problem. I want `.dismiss` to dismiss my notification. Why isn't it? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**
I see now that these two scenarios are happening:

1. I 3D-touch my notification from the lock screen, then tap outside it, my notification 'collapses' and the regular notification is visible as it was before I 3D-touched it.
2. I 3D-touch my notification from the lock screen, tap 'Snooze' (and nothing happens), then tap outside the notification, and the regular notification disappears.

So the completion callback actually does dismiss the regular notification, but not the extension. Why? How can I dismiss the extension? Is that a manual method I must call?

Comment: I'm confused about your problem. Do you mean when you press snooze...it then opened the app but the snooze notification was still still on top of your screen?

Comment: @Honey If I called the completion handler with `.dismissAndForwardAction` it opened my app. If I called the completion handler with `.dismiss`, nothing happened at all (e.g it did neither dismiss nor open the app). Turned out the problem was when I initialised the notificationAction though. Evidently, `UNNotificationActionOptions` describes what the button does, and `UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption` describes what the notification should do after the action has happened. Turns out that the notification's `.dismiss` doesn't pair well with the button's `.foreground`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see my stupid mistake now..

As you can see in my code above, I have instantiated the action button in my category as such:

```
let snooze = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "snoozeActionIdentifier", title: NSLocalizedString("SNOOZE", comment: ""), options: .foreground)
```

At the very end, I specify the option `.foreground`. This should simply be an empty array `[]` for my purpose.

I thought I had to specify *an* option, and that the input type was of `UNNotificationActionOptions`, which only had the options `.authenticationRequired` ("no I don't want that") `.destructive` ("no I don't want a red button") and `.foreground` ("well, if I have to pick *one* if these.."). Turns out that simply specifying an empty array `[]` did the trick.

Comment: thanks for this!  Not a stupid mistake at all, I thought the same thing.  This should be an optional or have better documentation.  Thanks again!

Comment: Adding to that you can use default argument for options  ```UNNotificationAction(identifier: typeIdentifier, title: title)```